# Convert JSON to XML where JSON key contains : which is not allowed in XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

My source JSON file have : in the key as mentioned below

`"Dimension 4 : 4 : 4" : "4k TV"`

My JSON to XML converter fails as this is not allowed and throws this exception

`System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

What should be the proper way to convert this JSON in valid XML file?

I have tried normal conversion which does not work, and this should not be considered as namespace also as this is not namespace but just some text.

Comment: What is your actual goal here?

Comment: After converting JSON to XML, we convert this XML to a specific XML format for data extraction.

Comment: And what does the XML->XML routine or data extraction routine require `"Dimension 4 : 4 : 4"` to become?

Comment: Does it need to roundtrip (should you be able to convert the XML value back to JSON, or reference it otherwise as-is)? Can you split this particular element into a complex element like `<Foo><Name>Dimension 4 : 4 : 4</Name><Value>4k TV</Value></Foo>`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama As of now we can replace it with some other allowed character like '-' so that processing does not stop.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution already.

Comment: @CodeCaster we don't need to convert it back to JSON, we can not convert it to a complex element like this because further processing is not ready to understand this format.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, what will be the best optimized way to take care of this because we are going to only replace this character for JSON keys only, not values and we are processing thousands of files like this at a time so performance should not be impacted.

Comment: Well, you must be going through the JSON bit-by-bit already to convert it to an XML file, so just do the at the point where you're ready to generate the corresponding XML element. A dictionary lookup of JSON key to XML element name might improve performance if you have a lot of repeated JSON keys like this.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Just for your reference we are using JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode from Newtonsoft library for conversion.

Comment: But why do you use a _value_ as an _element name_ to begin with? Is this whole application schemaless? What happens if you change it to `Dimension 4 _ 4 _ 4`?

Comment: In that case, could you perhaps use [this overload](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXNode_3.htm) with `encodeSpecialCharacters` set to `true`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: @Charlieface I was hoping that OP could confirm if that was a suitable solution or not. I'm not really sure how it encodes these characters as I've never used that method, so it might not be suitable for OP's subsequent processes.

Comment: There is no "proper" way. There are many ways of doing it, and which one to choose depends on your project requirements and constraints.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama this worked for me as how dbc answered, it will replace the space and : with x0020 and x003A. As of now it is fine but this might need one extra layer of work when the proper string is required so it needs to be decoded again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

- [`JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(value, deserializeRootElementName, writeArrayAttribute, bool encodeSpecialCharacters)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXNode_3.htm), or
- [`JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(value, deserializeRootElementName, writeArrayAttribute, bool encodeSpecialCharacters)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXmlNode_3.htm), or
- [`XmlNodeConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter.htm) with [`EncodeSpecialCharacters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter_EncodeSpecialCharacters.htm) specified to be `true`

with `encodeSpecialCharacters : true` to convert your JSON to XML:

```
var node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, null, false, 
                                        encodeSpecialCharacters : true);
```

As explained in the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXNode_3.htm), this parameter is:

> A value to indicate whether to encode special characters when converting JSON to XML. If true, special characters like ':', '@', '?', '#' and '$' in JSON property names aren't used to specify XML namespaces, attributes or processing directives. Instead special characters are encoded and written as part of the XML element name.

The name is encoded using the standard .NET method [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname) and thus may be recovered using [`XmlConvert.DecodeName(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename).

Thus:

```
var json = """{"Dimension 4 : 4 : 4" : "4k TV"}""";

var node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, null, false, 
                                        encodeSpecialCharacters : true);
foreach (var child in node.Descendants())
{
    var name = child.Name.LocalName;
    var originalName = XmlConvert.DecodeName(child.Name.LocalName);
    Console.WriteLine($"Encoded name: {name}"); //Dimension_x0020_4_x0020__x003A__x0020_4_x0020__x003A__x0020_4
    Console.WriteLine($"Original name: {originalName}"); //Dimension 4 : 4 : 4
}
```

Prints:

```
Encoded name: "Dimension_x0020_4_x0020__x003A__x0020_4_x0020__x003A__x0020_4"
Original name: "Dimension 4 : 4 : 4"
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sIukLs).

Comment: This solves one part of the problem, now if we have to read this node from XML and get the original value then what should be the approach? @dbc

Comment: @sarawgeek - not sure I understand the problem.  `encodeSpecialCharacters : true` only changes element names, not element values.  But if you need to get the original name, use `XmlConvert.DecodeName()` as mentioned in the answer.  Incidentally `XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName()` is reversible via `XmlConvert.DecodeName()`, so there's no possibility of two different JSON property names being encoded to the same XML element name.

Comment: Got it @dbc, I have missed that part in your answer, apologies..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to be able to preserve the data, the way I would approach this would be to write some normalization API that removes invalid characters (spaces, whatever else you find) or replaces them with other tokens, then *if the name and normalized name are different*, make use of an attribute in a custom xml namespace (typically aliased), so you end up with:

```xml
<Dimension_4_4_4 mytool:name="Dimension 4 : 4 : 4"><!-- content --><Dimension_4_4_4>
```

and then reverse this process as needed.

Note however, that `Dimension 4 : 4 : 4` seems a lousy name in either json or xml meanings.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this name is one of the example I have used here to ask question and it is not real data, but real data follow this format.